# project.wpp.targets is not being executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild, publishing

So, I have a solution, inside solution I have more than 50 projects. My main project is ADd.Vet.Web.Api, so my wpp.targets file is ADd.Vet.Web.Api.wpp.targets.

Whatever I put there, it is not being executed.

These are the links that i'm using as references and from these links I have tried to make it work:

[link1](http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html)
[link2](http://miniml.ist/dotnet/how-to-prevent-overwrites-during-deployment/)

The thing im trying to do is next:
When publishing app, I don't want to publish my Web.config, but also, I don't want it to be deleted from the publish folder(everything else needs to be deleted)